# Mvc DropdownList default selected value by ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have filled a viewbag and bound a dropdownlist to it ..like below

```
var countrylist = ctx.Countries.ToList();
ViewBag.countrylist = new SelectList(countrylist, "ID", "Name",2);

@Html.DropDownList("countrylist", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrylist, "-Select-")
```

Above I wanted to by default select the second item of countrylist, so I mentioned the value "2" as last parameter of the ViewBag countrylist overload.
But it is not selecting that item by default.

However, If I change the dropdownlist name to something else like below

```
@Html.DropDownList("countrylist12345", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.countrylist, "-Select-")
```

then it will by default select the 2nd item in countrylist.

Please explain why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Your whole view is most likely strongly typed with some model

```
@model YourNamespace.SomeModel
```

This model has a field `countrylist` which has some value, maybe 0 by default. And because the name of this field is the same as the name of the dropdown itself, the value of this field is what the dropdown uses to determine the default selection. Once you change the name of the dropdown, the connection is gone.

What you can do is make sure that this model you use to strongly type your view is being assigned some value in `countrylist` field. For example, inside the controller:

```
SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
model.countrylist = 2;
return View(model);
```

Comment: no bro my view is not strongly bound. I was just practicing with dropdownlists and found this erratic behavoir i dont know why this is happening. Is it some convention or what ?